# How to fix ClassNotFoundException: kotlinx.coroutines.debug.AgentPremain in debug?

Tags: kotlin, intellij-idea

I am running several projects as spring boot applications, one of them specifically cannot start and is throwing:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: kotlinx.coroutines.debug.AgentPremain
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:352)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351)
    at sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.loadClassAndStartAgent(InstrumentationImpl.java:304)
    at sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.loadClassAndCallPremain(InstrumentationImpl.java:401)
Exception in thread "main" FATAL ERROR in native method: processing of -javaagent failed
Disconnected from the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:64279', transport: 'socket'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

The command line has the option:

```
-javaagent:[...].m2/repository/org/jetbrains/kotlinx/kotlinx-coroutines-core/1.5.0/kotlinx-coroutines-core-1.5.0.jar
```

And this jar exists.

this happened after updating my Intellij'Idea to 2021.2

This issue happens only in **debug** mode.

Any idea how to solve this?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

It is a known problem in the Kotlin plugin. As a workaround disable the coroutine agent option under `Settings/Preferences | Build, Execution, Deployment | Debugger | Data Views | Kotlin | enable "Disable coroutine agent"`.

Please follow https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KTIJ-19345 , for updates.

[image]

Comment: The ticket states that this bug is fixed. But it is not. The bug still occurs in IntelliJ 2021.3

Comment: i've been dealing with issues for months and did some research and finally here is the solution thumbs up

Answer (score 9):

Newer versions of IntelliJ have this option under `Settings/Preferences | Build, Execution, Deployment | Debugger`

[image]

Comment: Double clicking shift and searching for "Disable coroutine agent" takes you right to it wherever it is.  Hopefully this is helpful for any future moves of this configuration.