# IntelliJ ClassNotFoundException AgentPremain

Tags: kotlin, intellij-idea

I have IntelliJ IDEA 2022.3.1 (Community Edition)

When i started my spring boot project in debug mode, i have the below error

```
Connected to the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:57235', transport: 'socket'
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: kotlinx.coroutines.debug.AgentPremain
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:581)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
    at java.instrument/sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.loadClassAndStartAgent(InstrumentationImpl.java:431)
    at java.instrument/sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.loadClassAndCallPremain(InstrumentationImpl.java:525)
*** java.lang.instrument ASSERTION FAILED ***: "result" with message agent load/premain call failed at ./src/java.instrument/share/native/libinstrument/JPLISAgent.c line: 422
FATAL ERROR in native method: processing of -javaagent failed, processJavaStart failed
Disconnected from the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:57235', transport: 'socket'
```

I found this solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/68754169/4739210, but i don't found `Kotlin` under `Data Views`

[image]

Comment: In the latest build (2022.3 currently), this option is located under `Settings/Preferences | Build, Execution, Deployment | Debugger | Kotlin` (https://prnt.sc/f-N-hIE3d82z)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ran into the same error and in the latest version (2022.3.3) of IntelliJ, the setting can still be found under

> Settings/Preferences | Build, Execution, Deployment | Debugger | Kotlin

like Igor Klepikov mentioned in his comment. (Thanks!)

[image: IntelliJ settings Kotlin]